# Dictionary calls within dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

so I am trying to call a dictionary within a dictionary and use the keys as values, but I every attempt to reach it has failed so far. This is where I am , note that all print statements after the if expression fail.

```
def main():
    print("This program tells you about the animal of your choice")
    animal=input("What animal would you like to look up: ")
    animal=animal.lower()

    d2={
        "lion":{"name":"Lion","species":"Panthera leo",
        "image":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lion_waiting_in_Namibia.jpg", 
        "fact":"Vulnerable species"},
    "dog":{"name:":"Dog","species":"Canis lupus familiaris", 
        "image":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg",
        "fact":"Common house pet"},
        "hippo":{"name":"Hippo","species":"Hippopotamus amphibius",
                  "image":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippopotamus#/media/File:Hippopotamus_-_04.jpg",
                  "fact":"Erbivorous mammal"},
        "cat":{"name":"Cat","species":"Felis catus",
                "image":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat#/media/File:Cat_poster_1.jpg",
                "fact":"Purring hunters"}
        }
    if animal in d2:
        print(d2(animal["name"]), "is the common name")
        print(d2(animal["species"]), "is its latin name")
        print(d2(animal["image"]), "is a picture of", animal)
        print(d2(animal["fact"]),)
    else:
        print("Not in dicionary, try lion, dog, hippo, or cat")
main()
```

Comment: Some indents dissapeared as i pasted the code, so thats why text look so jumbled in d2

Comment: `dict` elements are accessed by `[]`, not `()`.

Comment: Do you notice that you're using parentheses instead of brackets to access the dictionary?

Comment: Brackets around animal still gives this error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
print(d2(animal["name"]), "is the common name")
```

Indicates you are treating `d2` as a function. Instead, try

```
animal_dict = d2.get(animal, {})
animal_name = animal_dict.get("name")
print("%s is the common name" % animal_name)
```

and so on..

Comment: You don't need `.keys()` in Python 3.

Comment: dont agree on your first stmt... if animal in d2 is same as if animal in d2.keys() and animal in d2 is preferred and concise....

Comment: Agreed ! It is the same with Python2 as well. I meant it was better to be explicit :)

Comment: Thank you! I see how i totally forgot about the .get() function. Have a great day!

Comment: It may not be as explicit, but `if key in mydict` is preferred.

Comment: uhh, don't be _that_ explicit.  in python 2, `animal in d2.keys()` can be significantly slower than `animal in d2`!  defeats half the point of using a dict

Comment: Yup @TigerhawkT3 Just did a timeit.. you are right. `.keys` is slower

Comment: And in Python 2 you'd probably want to use `iterkeys()` instead of `keys()` in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple, tought. See...

```
print(d2(animal["name"]), "is the common name")
```

This means "print the return value of calling `d2` (with the single argument as the object at index `"name"` in `animal`) and the string `"is the common name"`".

This makes no sense at all, no? You can't use parentheses (the call operator, `()`), to "call" dictionaries. Does that makes sense to you? IHMO, that makes no sense.

Instead, you should *index* the dictionary with key `animal`. But, from what appears to have happened according to the comments, you tried this...

```
 d2[animal["name"]]
```

This means: "object at index (object at index `"name"` in `animal`) in `d2`". Again, that makes no sense. The correct way is...

```
 d2[animal]["name"]
```

This means "object at index `"name"` in object at index `animal` in `d2`". Now, that makes sense! You should apply the same change pattern to all your print statements.

Why this happens? `d2` is a dictionary of dictionaries. Thus...

```
x = d2[animal]
```

Means "store the object at index `animal` in `d2` in `x`". Then...

```
x["name"]
```

Means "object at index `"name"` in `x`". Now, that makes sense to you? ;).

**Edit**: For those mislead by historical reasons, (almost) **never** use `input()` in Python 2.x, unless you know what you're doing! Use `raw_input()` (same interface) instead.

I hope this has led some light on you!

Comment: Yes, thank you. However, using your method gets me a KeyError on name... Are you sure I can write print(d2[animal]["name"])

Comment: @M.gnus: If you're on Python2, use `raw_input()`, and **never** use `input()` (unless you're on Python3).